# How get rows and group by in one select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Code:

```
SELECT ta.name AS ta_name,
       ta.unit  AS ta_unit,
       ta.id_producer_goods AS ta_id_producer_goods
    FROM   Table ta
    WHERE  id_city = '24'
           AND id_firm = '22131'
           AND id_service = '5'
```

In select me need get rows with group by ta_name(result should include only unique ta_name) and get count of each unique ta_name in all table.

How do it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems too simple--but here is what I'm understanding you need.

```
SELECT ta.name AS ta_name,
  ta.unit              AS ta_unit,
  ta.id_producer_goods AS ta_id_producer_goods, COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE ta
WHERE id_city  = '24'
AND id_firm    = '22131'
AND id_service = '5'
GROUP BY ta.name, ta.unit, ta.id_producer_goods
```

Comment: Not! also me need get ta.unit AS ta_unit, ta.id_producer_goods AS ta_id_producer_goods AND count unique each ta.name in table. you show not aright code.

Comment: Then I would rephrase your statement and take out this "result should include only unique ta_name" -- I'll update the SQL to see if understand what you're saying

Comment: I updated the statement to count all the records where the name, unit, id_producer_goods are the same.

Comment: really? your code `GROUP BY ta.name, ta.unit, ta.id_producer_goods`. in my question i said that me need do gorup only by `ta.name`. your code not argiht for my question...

Comment: Then I would comment that you need to make the problem statement a bit more clear---I'm trying to help here and you not expanding on what you need isn't helping. The problem isn't very clear.

Comment: first `GROUP BY ta.name,ta.unit,ta.id_producer_goods` group rows on 3 parametrs but me need only by `ta.name`

Comment: see please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024021/can-to-do-one-query-from-two-queries

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(ta.name)
            ,   ta.name AS ta_name
            ,   ta.unit AS ta_unit
            ,   ta.id_producer_goods AS
                ta_id_producer_goods
FROM [table] ta
WHERE id_city = '24'
    AND id_firm = '22131'
    AND id_service = '5'
GROUP BY
        ta.name
    ,   ta.unit
    ,   ta.id_producer_goods
```

Comment: no, no - first `GROUP BY ta.name,ta.unit,ta.id_producer_goods` group rows on 3 parametrs but me need only by `ta.name`

Comment: see please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024021/can-to-do-one-query-from-two-queries