# Can to do one query from two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two query:

1) first i find all unique `name` and count each unique `name` in `Table`

2) second i get rows for each unique `name`

Code:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT name, count(name) as count
    FROM (
        SELECT name
            FROM Table
            WHERE id_city='333' AND id_firm='444' AND id_service='555'
    ) x
    GROUP BY name
";

$res1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);

while ($i = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $name = ($i['name'] != '') ? $i['name'] : '0';

    $sql2 = "SELECT 
        ta.unit as ta_unit,
        ta.id_producer_goods as ta_id_producer_goods
        FROM Table ta
        WHERE ta.id_city='333'
            AND ta.id_firm='444'
            AND ta.id_service='555'
            AND ta.name='$name'";

    $params = array();
    $options = array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
    $res12 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql12, $params, $options);
}
```

**Sql Fiddle with structure table [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/27daa)**

***Can to do one query from two queries?***

Comment: show table structure and desired output..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the unit and producer_goods fields have more than one row per name and you want to show them all.

```
SELECT ta.[Name],
    (SELECT count([Name]) FROM [Table] tc 
        WHERE tc.[Name] = ta.[Name]
        AND ta.id_city='333' 
        AND ta.id_firm='444' 
        AND ta.id_service='555'
    ) as [Name Count],
    ta.unit as ta_unit,
    ta.id_producer_goods as ta_id_producer_goods
    FROM [Table] ta
    WHERE ta.id_city='333' 
        AND ta.id_firm='444' 
        AND ta.id_service='555' 
    ORDER BY ta.[Name]
```

Comment: Then I don't understand what you're looking for. Please post the columns and rows you would expect to see in the final results.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use two querires. Since the group function called in first query will retur only one row.
While you need multiple rows according to point 2 of your requirements.